# ¿Cómo ajustar el drawable del Splash Screen de Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy ocupando un `layer-list` en un drawable pero el resultado que estoy obteniendo para el splash screen es muy diferente al que necesito.

Actualmente se ve así mi ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que se vea justo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado la forma de poner como fondo un `layout` en lugar de un `drawable` pero lo que me doy cuenta es que no es posible. De igual forma me gustaría saber si es posible hacer que se vea como el ejemplo que di en mi código que ocupo para mi splash screen el cual es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/color_splash"/>

    <item android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/logo_blanco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Antes estaba intentando ocupar un layout en lugar de un drawable el cual era este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2196F3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_blanco" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Aún así, no consigo que el resultado sea el que necesito. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Fíjate en el tamaño que tiene lo que quieres poner pues tu imageView dice wrap content puedes probar ya que estás utilizando constriant 0dp de ancho y como referencia le pones parent a la derecha y la izquierda más un margen y debe quedarte tal como lo necesitas te lo aseguro 

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas agregar un layerlist, simplemente has referencia a el vector asset dentro de `/drawable`

agrega tu `ImageView` dentro de un `RelativeLayout` con la propiedad  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` y a tu ImageView define las propiedades             `android:layout_width="match_parent"` y `android:layout_height="match_parent"` para que tome el ancho del RelativeLayout
:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dell_logo"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

De esta forma asegurarás que la imagen vectorial se muestre siempre dentro del area del layout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y lamento la demora. Apenas me pude conectar. Fíjate que mi duda con esto es saber el proceso correcto para poder decirle a mi <style> que creé dentro de mi styles.xml que ocupe un layout en lugar de un drawable? Actualmente tengo algo como <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item> donde @drawable/splash hace referencia al layerlist que puse en la pregunta. Pero no se ve bien y en su lugar quiero usar el layout con constraint layout que también puse en la pregunta. Pero cuando lo hago, me marca error al compilar la app y también con el código tuyo